MOSFET switch unreliable
I am using a MOSFET to drive a lamp from an Arduino Uno R4 with 5V level pins with the following configuration:

(EDIT: typo in the schematics, R2 is connected after R1, but that gives just a 1% voltage drop in the divider).
The physical circuit (ignore the cap, is unplugged):


When I power it on, the lamp either doesn't turn fully on, or just dims a little when off; often both. I normally need to toggle it on and off a few times before it works reliably. If I leave the circuit energised, but the lamp off for a while, it stops working again.
Example of lamp on and off upon boot (the toggle at the top is sensed by a GPIO pin that activates the other):

[
As we cycle, the lamp becomes brighter when on and dimmer when off. Plugging the board off and quickly on again keeps it working. If I de-energise, short the legs of the transistor to release any charge, and plug it again quickly, it still works.
Poking around with the multimeter the gate cross the threshold with margin in both directions.
The transistor is a DIT050N06, and the lamp draws 1 A at 5V. The maximum current of the pin the Arduino can put is 8 mA. I need to turn the lamp on for about a second at the time, and I don't need very fast switching times.
What am I doing wrong? Is that the wrong part?

How is the circuit physically implemented. Please edit some pictures into the question.

Is this a filament lamp or a module with high turn on current far above 1 A?

How much is on and off time currently programmed.better check lamp directly with supply to be sure problem is not on that part.

This circuit looks fine. Either you have a wiring problem, a bad MOSFET, or you are not controlling PIN potential correctly.

Please understand most people don't know what an "Arduino R4" is and how it works. A far more better would be to say that you have an random MCU with GPIO voltage is 3.3V or 5V. Which one is it?

@Jens a halogen lamp.

@SimonFitch since it works once it is warmed up, I think the wiring should be fine. Bad MOSFET is a possibility. Is it possible to test it while it is soldered on?

Very poor datasheet for DIT050N06. Impossible to tell if 5 V is enough for 1 A drain current. Try increasing your 15 kohm pull-down to 100 kohm. Get yourself a proper MOSFET with a transconductance graph showing that 5 V gate is enough for your application.

@winny any suggestion for a good MOSFET? Even if it doesn't work for my application, as a way of comparing datasheets.

117 to choose from here: https://rb.gy/m5wpuh

@vir added the photos and more debugging information.

I don't see a solder link between the two resistors and the blue gate wire.

Your 120 ohm resistor is probably 10 kohm, check it..

@Jens no on the resistor, although they do look identical. That was actually my first mistake, but I got one new from the box and double-checked with the multimeter. :)

@Jens the missing link was the problem! The reason it sort of worked was because of a thin connection between the two, but with a very large resistance, letting some current through.
If you write it as an answer I will accept it. Thank you very much!

The MOSFET gate is not connected to the resistors.
The red circle marks the issue. There may be a weak connection with very high resistance, that provides partial functionality.
The intended connection of R2 is a direct connection between gate and GND in the picture, but in your circuit it is placed on the GPIO side of R1.


Good catch. Seems like the gate is floating entirely..!
